# Is there a way to sort this dataset by subscription + equipment and subscription + No equipment?

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ChOy.png)

This is the dataset that I have where transaction Ids are duplicate having 1 or more things in cart that is shown as product. I need filter out data that has subscription + equipment

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out data that has words such as "monthly" or "plan". Take a look at [this site](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2722-excel-filter-based-on-substring.html). In summary:

- Go to **data** at the top of your nav bar in Excel and click **filter**
- Click **text filters** > **contains**

Now you can get rid of those strings and add custom filters based off on your data table